How to redirect an exception that was caught by a middleware back to a controller's action method in C# ASP.NET Core?
Lately, I have been trying to implement a strategy for dealing with exceptions in my C# ASP.NET Core application with no success.
This strategy is structured in two parts:
The first is to have a piece of middleware solely responsible for dealing with a given custom type of exception that my application may throw. If one is detected, this middleware should be capable of redirecting it back into a specific controller's action that knows how to handle this type of exception.
The second part is the controller that handles this exception sent by the middleware. Ideally, I would like to retrieve the exception (within my controller's endpoint) by means of the HttpContext.Features.Get method.
Nevertheless, despite my attempts, the returned feature is returned as null; thus, no exception is retrieved by my controller (see type definitions in the code shown below).
I would like to point out that this question arose from a deep search of alternative strategies found online (like the ones found in here, and here), and from the Microsoft's documentation itself.
I thank you for your time. Any help is appreciated.
Types definitions
Controller:
public class ExceptionManagerController : AppController
{
    public ExceptionManagerController() : base()
    {
    }

    [ResponseCache(Duration = 0, Location = ResponseCacheLocation.None, NoStore = true)]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Index()
    {
        var exceptionHandlerPathFeature = HttpContext.Features.Get<IExceptionHttpContextFeature>();

        var excecao = exceptionHandlerPathFeature?.Exception;

        if ( excecao == null)
        {
            return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
        }
        else
        {
            var vm = new GlobalExceptionVM(excecao);

            return View(vm);
        }
    }
}

HttpContext.Feature's custom interface:
public interface IExceptionHttpContextFeature
{
    Exception Exception { get; }
}

Custom interface's implementation:
public class ExceptionHttpContextFeature: IExceptionHttpContextFeature
{
    public Exception Exception {get;}

    public ExceptionHttpContextFeature()
    {
    }

    public ExceptionHttpContextFeature(Exception exception)
    {
        this.Exception = exception;
    }
}

Middleware:
public class GlobalExceptionHandler : IExceptionHandler
{
    private ILogger<GlobalExceptionHandler> Logger;

    public GlobalExceptionHandler(ILogger<GlobalExceptionHandler> logger)
    {
        Logger = logger;
    }

    public async ValueTask<bool> TryHandleAsync(HttpContext httpContext, Exception exception, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        if ( exception != null)
        {
            var originalBodyStream = httpContext.Response.Body;
            Logger.LogError($"Erro na solicitação do usuário {httpContext.User.Identity.Name}. Error Message: {exception.Message}, Time of occurrence {DateTime.UtcNow}");
            httpContext.Response.StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.BadRequest;
            httpContext.Response.Redirect("/GestorDeExcecoes/Index");
            httpContext.Features.Set<IExceptionHttpContextFeature>(new ExceptionHttpContextFeature(exception));
        }

        return true;
    }
}


Your controller could not get the exception by the method: HttpContext.Features.Get. That is because the HttpContext is specific to the current HTTP request. When you perform a redirection in the middleware, a new HTTP request is created, and the HttpContext for the new request does not carry over the features from the original request.
To solve the problem, you can use the session to save the exception message, below is the working code:
1.Add a session in your middleware
public async ValueTask<bool> TryHandleAsync(HttpContext httpContext, Exception exception, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
    if (exception != null)
    {
        // add a session to save the exception.
        httpContext.Session.SetString("ErrorMessage", exception.Message);
        Logger.LogError($"Erro na solicitação do usuário {httpContext.User.Identity.Name}. Error Message: {exception.Message}, Time of occurrence {DateTime.UtcNow}");
        httpContext.Response.StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.BadRequest;
        httpContext.Response.Redirect("/ExceptionManager/Index");           
    }
    return true;
}

2.Get the session value in your controller
public class ExceptionManagerController : AppController
{
    public ExceptionManagerController() : base()
    {
    }

    [ResponseCache(Duration = 0, Location = ResponseCacheLocation.None, NoStore = true)]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Index()
    {
        // get the exception from the session
        var excecao = HttpContext.Session.GetString("ErrorMessage");
        if (excecao == null)
        {
            return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
        }
        else
        {
            var vm = new GlobalExceptionVM(excecao);
            return View(vm);
        }

    }
}

3.Register this session service and configure the session middleware in Program.cs
builder.Services.AddSession();

builder.Services.AddExceptionHandler<GlobalExceptionHandler>();

var app = builder.Build();

app.UseSession();

app.UseExceptionHandler(opt => { });

